# HSTS Preload differing results

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, preload, hsts

On one of my sites I have `Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS` and this was enough for HSTS to be preloaded but the exact same snippet in my `.htaccess` file doesn't allow preloading on another site. I've went with `Header set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS` which fixed the issue but I'm wondering why the shorter version worked and preloaded a the first site but not the second?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK you’ve always needed both `includeSubDomains;` and the `preload` attributes to be considered for the preload submission tool. Are you sure you are not setting them in your other site? Maybe in different config?

Comment: The config on both was identical which is why I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

> why the shorter version worked

The short version couldn't have "worked". It would have been sufficient to implement HSTS, but not to have been accepted for the [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/).

Something else in your config must have been sending the complete header.

The only way to confirm what is actually going on is to record the HTTP request/response headers being sent on the request, not by the directives in your (`.htaccess`?) config file.

Even the directive you posted is not necessarily sufficient by itself. You must have something that is setting the `HTTPS` environment variable (this is not the same as the `HTTPS` *server* variable). And if you have canonical redirects from www to non-www (or vice versa) then you are missing the `always` argument to set the header on the 301 redirect (HTTPS only) - which is also a requirement of the "preload list".

It is far easier and less prone to error to implement HSTS "preload" in the server config. If you only have access to `.htaccess` then I would be hesitant to go for "preload list" submission.

See also [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/251218/6744) to the following related question on CodeReview SE:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250805/hsts-recommendations-in-htaccess

Comment: The config on both was identical which is why I was confused. I apprecaite the information given in your response. I'm going to look into this more myself too to see what the difference was when they both use redirects and `.htaccess` in the same way.